# powers of the transition matrix for a subshift of finite type

Tags: probability-theory

Is there a relation between powers of the transition matrix for a subshift of finite type and iterations of the (forward) subshift?

It is very nice to understand the transition matrix via a graph and understand the space where the subshift acts on as all the possibilities to jump from one vertice to another (if it is allowed according to the matrix).

Now, let's say I consider the second power of the matrix, do the entries of it have a meaning in terms of the graph?  is there a relation between this new matrix and some iterations of the subshift (I guess the subshift compose with itself or something like that)?

Thank you in advance